# How To Change Username On This Site?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Would like to change it to DBGTBAH. Don't like my current username, and couldn't find it how to change it on here. It's out possible to do on my own? If not, where would I post this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it yourself from within your user profile.

Click on the favicon on the Stack Exchange yo bar (hovering over it with your mouse will show you current username).

This will take you to your Activity page and click on the menu option Profile at the top.

Here, under your Username and to the right of your chose favicon you will see in red `Click here to edit` unless you already have some text in 'about me' in which case you may have to click on Main User over on the right to give access to Edit profile and settings as shown in graphic 2 below.

After clicking on this option you will be able to edit your name as required (and change your picture to something else if desired) then go to the bottom f the page and select as required "Save changes just for this community" or " Save and copy changes to all public communities".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot find the "click here to edit" part in the *Profile* tab. I think that is visible in your case because you have your 'about me' part blank right now.

Comment: @pomsky You're right. Just changed my profile on Meta and the option disappears! Seems only lesser mortals with no 'about me' are encouraged to edit their profile? That said , the OP doesn't have any 'about me' set.

Comment: @pomsky but then again, if you click on Edit profile and settings and shown in the second graphic, it allows you to change the user name oand/or edit your 'about me' text.